# How to bind data in 'value' attribute of <input tag> to NET core MVC model using angular

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I’ve been playing around with Upload file - Streaming method. The original code, here:

[https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/mvc/models/file-uploads/sample/FileUploadSample](http://FileUploadSample)

However, I’m trying to get the data in the value attribute of `<input value=” ”>`  using Angular, the idea is that I can `POST` the value into my MVC model instead of whatever is typed by the user (as in the original code). So, I have done this change to the input value property.

Streaming/Index.cshtml:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
..

<input value="@Model.name” type="text" name="Name" ng-model="name"/>   
..
<button ng-click="createUser()">Create User</button>
..
 </div>
</div>

@section scripts{
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/app.js"></script>
}
```

However, with Angular code running under app.js, the following piece of code actually fails with **status code 400**. This is because the passed value is  “” and not the data under of value attribute of the HTML input tag.

App.js:

```
var User = (function () {
  function User(name) {
    this.name = name;

  }
  return User;
}());

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
      var modelSetter = model.assign;

      element.bind('change', function () {
        scope.$apply(function () {
          modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
        });
      });
    }
  };
}]);

myApp.service('userService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.createUser = function(user) {
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('name', user.name);


        return $http.post('/streaming/upload', fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': undefined
            }
        });
    };
}]);
```

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'userService', function ($scope, userService) {
  $scope.createUser = function () {
    $scope.showUploadStatus = false;
    $scope.showUploadedData = false;

      var user = new User($scope.name);

    userService.createUser(user).then(function (response) { // success
      if (response.status == 200) {
        $scope.uploadStatus = "User created sucessfully.";
        $scope.uploadedData = response.data;
        $scope.showUploadStatus = true;
        $scope.showUploadedData = true;
        $scope.errors = [];
      }
    },
    function (response) { // failure
      $scope.uploadStatus = "User creation failed with status code: " + response.status;
      $scope.showUploadStatus = true;
      $scope.showUploadedData = false;
      $scope.errors = [];
      $scope.errors = parseErrors(response);
    });
  };
}]);

function parseErrors(response) {
    var errors = [];
    for (var key in response.data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data[key].length; i++) {
            errors.push(key + ': ' + response.data[key][i]);
        }
    }
    return errors;
}
```

The solution must be a simple one, but after much research, I haven’t been able to find out how to modify it to make the data in the value=’’” attribute being passed across. This might be a stupid question but a headache for me however since I’m a total newbie regarding Angular. Please have some mercy, help.
Thanks

Comment: In general I'd say leave the .NET part out of the view just to keep it simpler in terms of debugging and keeping the backend decoupled from the front end (easier to write new clients or rewrite parts of the backend with other tech where appropriate).  `ng-model` typically handles updating the value on the input, if you wanted to load the value from the backend you'd just make a request in the controller (or a service/factory) to get the data from the backend and put it in an object/property you can reference from the view.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I agree,  I should be binding this data to a model using a controller. However, the nature of the streaming solution requires me to disable binding in the controllers via [DisableFormValueModelBinding] just as in the link I initially posted.  Would you please let me know if u can think in a better solution on how to bind this value? Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) directive to initialize the model:

```
<input ng-init="name= @Model.name" type="text" name="Name" ng-model="name"/>
```